# Can't install RVM on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

Good day!

I try to install RVM on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

My steps:

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )

$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then i open .bashrc and replace

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

With that

```
if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then
```

And that i add in the end of file

```
if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

fi
```

Then i try:

```
$ rvm notes
```

And i get:

```
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

What is wrong?! I tried my steps 100 times and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Have you logged in and logged out?

Comment: Yeah, that drove me crazy at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `.bashrc` file is executed when you open a new shell. Even though you changed it, you have to open a new shell or log out and back in for the changes to occur.